# mongoose $or within $or in find query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
this.find(query)
console.log(query)
{"$or":[{"colors":{"$in":["red"," blue"]}},{"type":"animal"}]}
```

why above query return only the first item of my 2 items below?

```
{
    colors: ["red"],
    type: "animal"
}

{
    colors: ["blue"],
    type: "insect"
}
```

Do I need $or within $or? What I want is get matched color or matched type, but above query gave me just one item.

Comment: I can't use $in here? colors is array.

Comment: You query works perfect... You can check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/r2qUB-Hcl8S... You missed space in `" blue"` color...

Comment: remove extra space from " blue"